# (Jacoco) code coverage for code shipped to Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, code-coverage, jacoco

We're using jacoco to measure code coverage for most of our system, and it works fine. However, code which is shipped to Apache Spark via spark-submit is inaccessible to that code coverage utility.

The internets indicates that we can attach jacoco to a running JVM process and have it gather coverage metrics from it runtime: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074515/core-java/unit-test-code-coverage-with-maven-and-jacoco.html

What is not clear is whether or not its possible to instrument the spark driver running our code using the jacoco agent so that it will measure coverage for the code we've shipped it.

Would love to hear from anybody who has tried to do this or something similar in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after struggling more with this, looks like the way to do this is via setting **spark.executor.extraJavaOptions** when calling spark-submit.

For example:

spark-submit --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:/Users/aron/dev/env/jacoco-0.7.4.201502262128/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/tmp/jacoco/jacoco.exec,includes=com.mypackages.*"

... will cause the spark process to use the jacoco agent specified when running your code to profile you packages (com.mypackages.* in the example above), and then dump the code coverage statistics into a file (/tmp/jacoco/jacoco.exec for example).

You can see details on how to invoke spark-submit with these types of parameters on http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html.

You can then instruct the jacoco to use the statistics dump to produce the coverage report! This is the approach I am going to take, I hope this helps someone.